# SqlDataAdapter does not fill up datatable but SQL statement works fine in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have trouble understanding why this doesn't work as it works for some of my SQL statements.

I am trying to populate a dataset using a `SqlDataAdpter` to store the select result and then use it to populate my result page

```
string sqlStr = "SELECT IRSwapId, " +  
                            "i.InventoryName ," +  
                            "Notional ," +  
                            "TradeDate," +  
                            "effectiveDate," +  
                            "MaturityDate," +  
                            "settleDate," +  
                            "FixedRate," +  
                            "ltrim(rtrim(cp.CounterParty))," +  
                            "MurexReference," +  
                            "case when PayReceiveFlag = -1 then 'Pay' else 'Receive' " +  
                            "end as PayReceiveFlag," +  
                            "ltrim(rtrim(c.currency)) ," +  
                            "fixedValue," +  
                            "floatValue," +  
                            "comments," +  
                            "CASE MurexUploadFlag WHEN 0 THEN 'N' WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' END " +  
                            "FROM IRSwaps irs, Currency c, CounterParty cp, Inventory i " +  
                            "WHERE i.InventoryID = irs.InventoryID AND cp.CounterPartyId = irs.CounterPartyId AND c.CurrencyID = irs.Currency " +  
                            "AND IRSTypeId = '2' " +  
                            (criteria == "" ? "" : " AND " + criteria + " ");
            return Strucfin.Instance.Query(sqlStr).Tables[0].Rows;

public DataSet Query(string sqlStr)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    lock (m_sfConn)
    {
        m_sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, m_sfConn);
        m_sqlDa.Fill(ds);
    }

    return ds;
}
```

But when I enter `ds.Tables[0].Rows` in the immediate table, it shows me nothing, the `sqlStr` that I took from the local windows works in SQL Server Management Studio.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you check your variable 'criteria ' it looks a bit off. Also can you post your connection?

Comment: Hi Causita, thanks for helping out. Criteria is a variable that I use to assemble the string. The connection should not have any problem as it is a generic object that I use a lot in my codes and it worked just fine.

Comment: OK.. SO when you debug in VS, grab the actual generated SQL String from the debugger and run in SQL Studio and run it. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah. I have tried exactly that, and the string from debugger runs in SQL Studio perfectly. That's why I find it so weird...